# cl.exe is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake

При выполнении команды:

`cmake.exe -G "NMake Makefiles" path_to_project`

Получаю ответ:

> -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- broken CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51
>   (message):   The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>     14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

Нашел такую же проблему [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590947/cmake-configuring-fails-cl-exe-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program), но ничего не помагает.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо выполнить:

`Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`

Скрипт настраивает окружение